# what is the meaning of "body" in a POST request?

Tags: http, curl, url, post

I am new to PHP. I have a stupid question and need your explanation.
When I make a POST request with the cURL command-line:

```
curl -d "username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost/Login
```

Please kindly let me know what is the purpose of this command-line. I just wonder whether data `"username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login"` will be attached to url `http://localhost/Login`. Then, we have:

```
http://localhost/Login/username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP POST is a method of sending data as an arbitrary package.  This is done in the http protocol, the POST data is sent in the "body", not the URL.

*HTTP GET is different, and it's GET that sends the data (restricted) in the URL.*

Therefore, in your example, the request will look (in a very simplified way) something like this:

```
POST /Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 42
username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login
```

The last line of this example is the body, whose length is specified in the HTTP header "Content-Length".

Here is an easy reference to show you the difference of POST and GET:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp